# mysql query count records with date in previous year

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with this fields

```
id    sell_date   
a1    27/7/2012
a1    26/7/2012
a1    24/7/2012
a1    24/2/2012
```

I want a count of the months who has sells in a period of one year before the current date.
result

`a1 = 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the datediff() function:

```
select count(id) as N 
from table_name
where datediff(curdate(), sell_date) >= 365;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Answer (score 4):

Assuming sell_date is DATE type:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(sell_date)) FROM `mytable` 
    WHERE id='a1' 
    AND sell_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Also,

removing `id='a1' AND` will get you the number of months with sales (in the last year period) associated to any id. Like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(sell_date)) FROM `mytable` 
    WHERE sell_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

also,

you can get a list of every id and the number of months with sales associated to that id in the last year, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id,MONTH(sell_date)) FROM `mytable` 
    WHERE sell_date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```